# Azure Data Factory: Migration of pipelines from one data factory to another

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have some pipelines which I want to move from one data factory to another. Is there any possible way to migrate them?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to just pull the git repo for the source factory down to your local file system and then just copy and paste the desired files into your destination factory folder structure.  That's it.

Alternatively, you can do this through the ADF editor by creating a shell of the pipeline in the target factory first, then go to the source factory and switch to the code view for that pipeline, copy and paste that code into the target pipeline shell you created, and then save from there.

A pipeline is just json.  You may need to copy the dependent objects also, but those are done the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

There is an import/export feature in the data factory canvas which supports this use case.

Moreover, this is the case where continuous deployment and integration proves very useful. More literature can be found - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment